# React/Redux Subscribe to the most recent state value emited by redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

in react if some new component mounted later and subscribed to a state that is changed multiple times before, the new component will render multiple times with all state values. is there a way to get most recent value of state only?

For example in angular: Subject emits most recent value while BehaviorSubject emits all values.

Answer (score 0):

you can Control your Child Component With a State Key  , and After All work Is done then You can set this state with true and render your child component base On this state.

```
{!!this.state.keyStateName && <yourComponnet />}
```

if is this text cant be useful please Release Some Code and explain it for better understanding your question